# Insert into temp values (select.... order by id)

Tags: sql, insert, informix

I'm using an  Informix (Version 7.32) DB. On one operation I create a temp table with the ID of a regular table and a serial column (so I would have all the IDs from the regular table numbered continuously). But I want to insert the info from the regular table ordered by ID something like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tempTable (id serial, folio int );

INSERT INTO tempTable(id,folio)
SELECT 0,folio FROM regularTable ORDER BY folio;
```

But this creates a syntax error (because of the ORDER BY)

Is there any way I can order the info then insert it to the tempTable?

UPDATE: The reason I want to do this is because the regular table has about 10,000 items and in a jsp file, it has to show every record, but it would take to long, so the real reason I want to do this is to *paginate* the output. This version of Informix doesn't have `Limit` nor `Skip`. I can't renumber the serial because is in a relationship, and this is the only solution we could get a fixed number of results on one page (for example 500 results per page). In the Regular table has skipped id's (called folio) because they have been deleted. if i were to put

```
SELECT * FROM regularTable WHERE folio BETWEEN X AND Y
```

I would get maybe 300 in one page, then 500 in the next page

Comment: There actually is no version 7.4 of any Informix DBMS (certainly not the mainstream ones - odd-balls like Redbrick, which Informix acquired shortly before IBM acquired Informix, might have such a version number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try it iterating a cursor over the SELECT ... ORDER BY and doing the INSERTs within the loop.

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that it involves a round trip from server to application to fetch and insert each row.  Nevertheless, it is the way that works.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by breaking up the SQL into two temp tables:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tempTable1 (
id serial,
folio int);

SELECT folio FROM regularTable ORDER BY folio
INTO TEMP tempTable2;

INSERT INTO tempTable1(id,folio) SELECT 0,folio FROM tempTable2;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Informix when using a SELECT as a sub-clause in an INSERT statement, you are **limited 
to a subset of the SELECT syntax**.

The following SELECT clauses are not supported in this case:

- INTO TEMP
- ORDER BY
- UNION.

Additionally, the FROM clause of the SELECT can not reference the same table as referenced by the INSERT (not that this matters in your case).

Answer (score 1):

It's been years since I worked on Informix, but perhaps something like this will work:

```
INSERT INTO tempTable(id,folio)
SELECT 0, folio 
FROM (
    SELECT folio FROM regularTable ORDER BY folio
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to order the rows as you insert into a table.  Relational databases do not allow you to specify the order of rows in a table.

Even if you could, SQL does not guarantee a query will return rows in any order, such as the order you inserted them.  You must specify an `ORDER BY` clause to guarantee an order for a query result.

So it would do you no good to change the order in which you insert the rows.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Bill, there's not a lot of point ordering the input, you really need to order the output. In the simplistic example you've provided, it just makes no sense, so I can only assume that the real problem you're trying to solve is more complex - deduplication perhaps?

The functionality you're after is `CREATE SEQUENCE`, but I'm pretty sure it's not available in such an old version of Informix.

If you really need to do what you're asking, you could look into `UNLOAD`ing the data in the required order, and then `LOAD`ing it again. That would ensure the SERIAL values get allocated sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT
    folio
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROWNUM n,
            folio
        FROM
            regularTable
        ORDER BY 
            folio
    )
WHERE
    n BETWEEN 501 AND 1000
```

It may not be terribly efficient if the table grows larger or you're fetching later "pages", but 10K rows is pretty small.

I don't recall if Informix has a ROWNUM concept, I use Oracle.

Comment: There's rowid... maybe it's the same