# Insert into table from another table after sorting data of first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing something like this in SP,

```
insert into @FilteredTbl select * from @MasterTbl
```

but now problem is that i want data of @MasterTbl sorted before adding into @FilteredTbl,

How can I do that ?

Comment: insert into at FilteredTbl (select * from  (select * from at MasterTbl order by field) as a)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/aeb1053d-0dc2-4dc3-96f5-8b213fed9669

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263101/insert-into-temp-values-select-order-by-id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserving ORDER BY in SELECT INTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424929/preserving-order-by-in-select-into)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
INSERT INTO @FilteredTbl 
SELECT * FROM @MasterTbl AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.OrderbyColumn
```

Comment: Am I missing something here....aren't all these solutions incorrect? The order is not guaranteed. 

_"4. INSERT queries that use SELECT with ORDER BY to populate rows guarantees how identity values are computed but not the order in which the rows are inserted"_

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx

Comment: Yes the above Query wont work as explained in the above link.

Answer (score 3):

Try following method to insert sort result into temp table. Use ROW_NUMBER to ORDER BY table result

```
DECLARE @FilteredTbl AS TABLE
(
    RowID INT
    [Column_1]
    [Column_2]
      .
      .
)

insert into @FilteredTbl 
select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY [ShortColumn]),[Field_1],[Field_2]... from @MasterTbl
```

Comment: With out "ROW_NUMBER()",  inserting data into a temp table with ordering is not working. working only with "ROW_NUMBER()" . thanks Jaylem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with adding id as identity to the declared table

in your case:

```
@FilteredTbl
 ID int identity not null,
 your columns...
```

When inserting sorted data it still sorted as it was

Answer (score -1):

You can use order by class in select statement

```
insert into @FilteredTbl 
    select * from @MasterTbl
    order by <column name>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please sort the table as you want before inserting into another table.

Like:

```
Select * From @MasterTbl m Order By m.ColumnName
```

then insert into your new table

```
Insert Into @FilterTbl Select * From @MasterTbl m Order By m.ColumnName [DESC]
```

You can also filter your @MasterTbl using `Where` Clause

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO @FilteredTbl SELECT * FROM @MasterTbl AS mtb ORDER BY mtb.OrderbyColumn [desc]
```

Here desc is optional if you want to order by your column in descending order than add ir otherwise no need to add

Answer (score -1):

You should add identity your table then It will sorted like that

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
    s int IDENTITY (1, 1),
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    part int
);

INSERT INTO  #test (ID,Name,Part)
SELECT ID, Name, Part FROM Table_1 ORDER BY ID DESC
SELECT * FROM #test
```

Comment: minus1 We don't need any extra column here as the table already has it's primary key.