# Listing data from database in hierachy and returning it in that order to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list data from database in a certain order then return it back to the database in that listed order.
Does any one of you have a clue of what i should do?

Comment: Specify Some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: mysql does not store data in any particular order (and you cannot force mysql to do so), if you want the data ordered in a select statement then you have to use an order by clause.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14424929/3404097. Tables have no order.

Comment: @philipxy . I will check out the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NOTE : Since **order** is a reserved keyword you can use any other
>   name for the column

This can be achieved by taking **order** column in your table.

For Eg:

```
id  taskname    order
1   firsttask   1
2   firsttask   2
3   firsttask   4
4   firsttask   3
5   firsttask   5
```

Then while fetching get it **order by asc** for **order** column

```
SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY order ASC
```

Now you may allow the user to add the order in which the items look like by text box or dragable of jquery and then while storing in the database table you can store it via that order