# Will the order of the data be retained from OLE DB Source to OLE DB Destination?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-order-by, ssis-2016, ssis-data-flow

In an SSIS package, I have a data flow task that contains an OLE DB Source and an OLE DB Destination.

The OLE DB Source is set to SQL command and has a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY Col1, Col2
```

Will the insertion of the records to the destination table follow the result of the order by?
I am asking because there is an identity column in the destination table which will be used as the order of the records.

EDIT: This question pertains to SSIS, specifically if the result set in the OLE DB source is passed to the OLE DB Destination in the same order and inserted in the same order as well. The order is relevant since the destination table has an identity column that would be used in queries as the records' order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserving ORDER BY in SELECT INTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424929/preserving-order-by-in-select-into)

Comment: There are 100s of questions and answers on this topic already. Specifically you should look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23237448/6305294

Comment: No, the question is different from mine and the answers really don't answer my question. I am asking asking specifically for SSIS OLE DB Source to Destination if the order of the result set translates from the OLE DB Source translate into the insertion to the OLE DB Destination since it has an identity.