# Write the result of the query into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Need to write the result to a table

```
select
    convert(datetime, dbo.time(table1.col1)) 
from 
    table1
order by 
    col1
```

Comment: Do you consider [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) or view?

Comment: @LeszekMazur computed column will work. Because, I am trying to further perform small operations on the resulting table

Answer (score 0):

Temp table (no order by):

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, dbo.time(table1.col1)) AS ConvertedDate
INTO #TempTable
FROM 
    table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, dbo.time(table1.col1)) AS col1
INTO #tableX
FROM table1
ORDER BY col1;
```

Comment: thanks. will a temp table slower the performance of the overall query?

Comment: ORDER BY have no sense in this: [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424929/preserving-order-by-in-select-into)

Comment: when I ran the suggested answer for the first time, it ran.
But when i tried to re-run, it says, "There is an already an object named '#tablex' in the database
I am in need of a solution that I can re-use. Is there an another way of doing it other than the temp table?

Comment: can you elaborate more on why you want it stored in a temp table? (which is what you wrote in the OP). of course you'll get that error if you run it again in the same scope, unless you run a IF EXISTS() ... DROP ... before it. (you can google for examples)

Comment: @RodneyEllis while I created the OP i didnt realize that this error would occur. I have now edited it. Thanks. Will use the If condition while running in the same schema

Comment: @new_user - don't forget to mark this as the answer to close the question.  :-)